# How to debug a serverless framework plugin?

Tags: node.js, typescript, serverless-framework

I've searched throughout google about this question and I had no success...

I want to work on a serverless plugin fix, but I don't know how to attach the process to debug the code.
Currently, I'm using vscode and the plugin was developed using nodejs + typescript.

Does anyone have any tip or article explaining how to do that?

Comment: Which serverless framework are you using?

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that you found this page about [TypeScript debugging in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging)? Additional clarification may be needed for good answers to your question. What have you tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every other process, that you want to debug, you need to run it and somehow connect the debugger to it.

You need to remember, that Serverless Framework is written in JS/TS, so it runs in Node.js. So you can debug it quite easily, if you are developing your Lambdas in Node.js, as it's quite common environment.

### How to do it using Jetbrains/Webstorm/IntelliJ

1. Go to your `node_modules` directory and find the source code of the plugin, that you want to debug.
2. In the source code place the breakpoint.
3. Now Create a new "Run configuration" in IDE for NPM, that should be similar to mine:
   [image: Run configuration for NPM]

4. Make sure you've chosen the correct `package.json`!

5. Now simply start debugging, like you normally do, but choose the run configuration, that you've just created.

In my example I'm using `package` script from package.json, but it could be also any other script, that triggers `serverless deploy` or `serverless print` in the end.

And that's it! Breakpoints should be triggered normally, like when you debug your own JS code.